# get id of selected items in ul in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I use symfony and twig, and I want to get all id the selected item using jquery and ajax.

this is my code

[image]

and this is the output

[image]

what I want, is a function in jquery that return for me a set of the selected items.

Comment: So what's selected here? From the HTML `login` looks like it's selected, but the image posted shows `login` as not selected, and there's two different classes for the selected elements ?

Comment: I don't need the login , I selected just five li, and I want to get the id of the five selected li

Comment: the login not selected, but the others in yellow yess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through each li in ul and add the ids to a variable:

```
var ids = [];
$('li.ui-selected').each(function(){
    ids.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: li is a tag, not a variable, you need to put quotes around it. Plus you can simplify the expression as $('li.ui-selected').each

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code now as per your suggestion